# Material Design using polymer nothing happen

Tags: polymer

i am totally new to this.

I downloaded new version of polymer archive from polymer-project.org

Codes are here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <script src="components/bower_components/bower_components/webcomponents/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="components/bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">

        <style type = "text/css">
            html,body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #E5E5E5;
                font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <paper-button>Test Button</paper-button>
        <paper-checkbox></paper-checkbox>


    </body>
</html>﻿
```

i tried everything over here. and can able to find any error or wrongs.

still dont have any button effect in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code.

One error I can think of is that you did serve the files through a server.

HTML `import`(s) work only when they are served through a server, this is because of some browser security issues, set-up a simple Node or Python server that should do plenty.

I cannot think of any other problem than this.